# Questions regarding timings and dates

Tags: discussion

Can *islam.se* be used as a platform for questions of the following ilk:

1. > When is the timing of jumma/[5 time prayer]/Eid-ul-*/etc in [...]?
2. > [When does the month of ramazan/[rest of the  11 month] start in [...]?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9180/3487)

Basically questions which are too specific and localized and will definitely be of no use to future user after a particular amount of time.

?

Comment: [Review in the edit page inconsistent with the one on display](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209639/221866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such questions are not a good fit for this site, they are (as you mentioned) very localized, and on top of that they have no academic value.  I believe that such questions should be closed as primarily opinion based, if not closed as off-topic as such questions have no relation to islam other then it is asking for dates of events, celebrations, or months that are very related and can be asked on here.

So in short, this site should not be used as such for it is not a date provider service, it is a place to learn about Islam on an academic and expert level.